# How do I access a list of possible dynamic controllers in HttpPost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have controls that insert from jQuery. The controls can change depending on the option you choose before, that is, they are not controls have created statically, but to think through jQuery with the option you choose.
My question is is possible to access a list of controller in HttpPost?

This is the function that performed to insert controls:

```
function GetProperties() {
        var subcategory = $("#ddlSubcategory").val();
        $.getJSON("/AddAdBox/GetProperties?id=" + subcategory, null, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                //item.ID // PROPERTY ID
                //item.NAME //NAME PROPERTY
                //item.OPTION_PROPERTY[0].ID //ID OPTION ID
                //item.OPTION_PROPERTY[0].NAME // NAME OPTION
                //item.OPTION_PROPERTY.length // SI ES 0 ES TXT SINO SELECT
                var itemlist = '';
                //<div class="col-sm-6">
                //                       <label>
                //                           Título
                //                       </label>
                //                       <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Título">
                //                   </div><!-- /.col -->
                if (item.OPTION_PROPERTY != null) {
                    if (item.OPTION_PROPERTY.length > 0) {
                        itemlist = '<div class="col-sm-6 animated" style="opacity:1;"><label>' + item.NAME + '</label>';
                        itemlist += '<select id="ddl"' + item.NAME + '">';
                        for (var i = 0; i < item.OPTION_PROPERTY.length; i++) {
                            itemlist += '<option value="' + item.OPTION_PROPERTY[i].ID + '">' + item.OPTION_PROPERTY[i].NAME + '</option>';
                        }
                        itemlist += '</selec>';
                        itemlist += '</div>';
                    }
                }
                else {
                    itemlist = '<div class="col-sm-6 animated" style="opacity:1;"><label>' + item.NAME + '</label>';
                    itemlist += '<input type="text" name="' + item.NAME + '" class="form-control" placeholder="' + item.NAME + '">';
                    itemlist += '</div>';
                }
                $("#properties").append(itemlist);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; "to access a list of controller[s] in HttpPost" would imply a controller action (in C#), but you've pasted a whole ton of what appears to be irrelevant (to that question) javascript and the question refers to controls and "controllers" (which is an mvc term) in a question tagged with asp.net-mvc which have zero relationship to each other.  Could just be a terminology issue.  Did you mean list of controls?  In which case you want `$(".form-control")` (all controls with class 'form-control') or `$("input")` (all inputs)

Comment: I want to acces to the list of dinamic controls on the post  [HttpPost] [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] Índice ActionResult pÃºblico (string id) {return View (); }

Comment: Assuming they're in the `<form>` element then members of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form` will give you all of the controls.

Comment: Your dynamically created `<select>` elements do not even have a `name` attribute so they don't post back anything (and what is the point of the `id` attribute?) And the textboxes your creating have random names and could not bind to anything. Suggest you look at the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to bind data to a controller, from dynamic HTML elements, is by using a custom model binder. For example:

In my controller I use a viewmodel:

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public int SelectedItemId { get; set; }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new IndexViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

I then create a custom model binder that can work with that viewmodel:

```
public class IndexViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                           ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string[] allKeys = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys;

        var viewModel = bindingContext.Model as IndexViewModel;

        viewModel.SelectedItemId = int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[0]);
    }
}
```

In your Global.asax.cs file, place this in the `Application_Start()`

`ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IndexViewModel), new IndexViewModelBinder());`

In my view file I have:

```
@model SelectListModelBinding.Controllers.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="col-sm-6 animated" style="opacity:1;">
        <label>FooName</label>';
        <select name="ddlFooName" id="ddlFooName">
            <option value="1">Item 1</option>
            <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

You can pretend that the `<select>` was dynamically generated. Now when I post back to the controller, the `IndexViewModelBinder` is executed and I can see the values passed in the `Form` property of the current request. I can then pick out whatever data I need. In my example I'm picking out the `id` of the selected list item from `ddlFooName`

Since the names of the dropdowns will be dynamic, you may have to do some stuff with the `Form.AllKeys` to pick out stuff that starts with "ddl" and use that key to get the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tomorrow proves